# How to get non english words in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, http, http-request-parameters

I am passing இயற்பியல் in subject name from Javascript to Java, while using alert in javascript.

```
alert(subject name);
```

இயற்பியல் is shown, whereas if I get value of subject name using

```
String subname=request.getParameter("subject name").toString;
```

..it's not returning.

Comment: How is subject name passed. Can you post the code ?

Comment: var url="GeneralAction.do"; var parameters="param=add_regulation&subject name="+subject name;

Comment: where is the subject name `இயற்பியல்` here that you r passing???

Comment: i am passing இயற்பியல் from javascript to action

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not returning"? What happens exactly?

Comment: Try to avoid space in the parameter name, that may also cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't put spaces in URL arguments. If you want to pass the subject name, use something like `"&subjectName="+encodeURIComponent(yoursubjectnamevar)`, and make sure to then unpack it in Java as well, because it'll now look like `%E0%AE%87%E0%AE%AF%E0%AE%B1%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%AF%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%8D`